# Visual Studio test runners & SpecFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, model-view-controller

I am going to improve my unit testing skills. I am ashamed because thoughout my years programming experience I don't practice writing tests in my projects. Now, I promise to myself change that.

I chose an interesting tutorial that shows a library (SpecFor, not SpecFlow) that can help me to provide more complex tests in MVC.NET.

http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/automated-testing-aspdotnet-specsfor

Everything is ok, but this approach causes a not fully satisfied summary view of a test result when I am using visual studio build-in test runner. There, I see only the method's name (for example: then_it_says_hi_to_user()) where a class name describing "when" syntax (where without "when" result view is not readable).

Simple example:

```
public class UserControllerSpecs
{
    public class when_viewing_the_index_action : SpecsFor<UserController>
    {
        //TODO: Put your result type here!

        private ActionResult _result;
        protected override void When()
        {
            //TODO: Put your action here!
            _result = SUT.Index();
        }

        [Test]
        public void then_it_says_hi_to_user()
        {
            _result.ShouldNotBeNull();
        }
    }   
}
```

Does anyone know which other test runners there may be to show me a test summary in way that helps me read that more clearly ?

Of course there is Resharper, and this kind of view is expected. But it is not cheap software and for me causes a lot of performance problems.

NCrunch is expensive.

NUnit GUI is an external tool, and it is not too comfortable switching between VS and NUnit.

TestDriven.Net doesn't show a friendly summary list.

Btw, does anyone know the "SpecFor" library ? Is it well known ? Is there a better approach to provide more complex tests for MVC.Net applications ?